# Cannot Validate/Distribute App where Xcode has 2 Accounts

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I use 2 different developer accounts: one for business and one for personal. The last account I used to publish an app was for business. Now when I try to publish an app for my personal account, I cannot see my app in the Application dropdown.

I have verified my provisioning profiles and certificates are correct. I have removed my business account and restarted my computer/xcode. The provisioning profile in Organizer is my personal one, but still the list of applications to validate/distribute are for my business account.

How can I tell Xcode which account to look at for these options?

Comment: Organizer should ask you to sign in to an account when you try to upload your app. Did you sign in to your personal account? Because it pulls the list of apps from iTunes Connect.

Comment: Yes, I selected the personal account once I saw that the apps listed there were for my business account. Unfortunately, the apps remained the ones for my business.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode > preference > account** add your accounts

in the project:

[image]

and if you want to enable your private account to distribute for a business account:

go to **developer center > member center > people > invitation** and invite your self, after that setting the permission for the account invited

[image]